# What does מטי ליה בחד שחיה mean regarding מלאכת צד on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, tzad-trapping

I found the following in קופת הרוכלים introduction to משניות שבת regarding מלאכת צד on Shabbos.
[image]

I believe there is a mistake being made. As per ביצה כד. it seems that if an animal is already trapped in a place that it can be grabbed easily מטי ליה בחד שחיה, this is a reason that there is no מלאכת צדה, not a reason for there to be מלאכת צידה.
Is this correct?
Thanks

Comment: The point is that the animal is currently *located* in the area where it could be easily grabbed, but is not yet *trapped* in that area. Since it could conceivably leave that area, it is not yet considered trapped until it is actually trapped in that area.